# Android: how to set text depending on available space

Tags: android, textview

I would like to be able to set the text in a TextView depending on the available space, in order to avoid ellipsizing.

For example:

- if there is enough space set the text "The red fox jumps"
- if there is not enough space (and consequently "The red fox jumps" would be ellipsized) set the text "jumps"

Please how can I achive that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Paint.measureText(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#measureText(java.lang.String)) to determine the width of the whole string, when drawn with your Paint object. If that value is greater than the TextView's width, then we know that the text will be ellipsised.

```
float totalLength = myPaint.measureText("The red fox jumps");
float tvWidth = myTextView.getWidth(); // get current width of TextView

if (tvWidth < totalLength) { 
    // TextView will display text with an ellipsis
}
```

Once we know the text will be truncated, we can use trial and error to determine what the minimum text that can be displayed on screen is. This step will depend on your business logic, but should use the same Paint calculations as the first step.

```
calculateStringWidth("The red fox jumps"); // too large
calculateStringWidth("red fox jumps"); // still too large
calculateStringWidth("fox jumps"); // width is less than TextView, will fit without ellipsis
```

Comment: Great answer! Does measureText returns width in pixels?

Comment: I believe so, most Android APIs return pixels.

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to calculate the neede size for given text.

```
textView.setText("The red fox jumps");
// call measure is important here
textView.measure(0, 0);
int height = textView.getMeasuredHeight();
int width = textView.getMeasuredWidth();
if (height > availableHeight || width > availableWidth) {
    textView.setText("jumps");
}
```

The call of measure() "determines the size requirements for this view and all of its children". Referring to Androids View doc. [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#measure(int,%20int))